# Automatically choose Auth0 DB Connection according to user's email address

Tags: auth0

I already read the [multi-tenancy guide](https://cdn2.auth0.com/docs/media/articles/architecture-scenarios/planning/Multiple-Organization-Architecture-Multitenancy-Users-Isolated-by-Organization.pdf) published, and I believe the solution I require for my app would be to create a separate DB Connection for each organization that I sign up.

My issue is that, since I'm going to be setting the `connection` parameter to a different name per client, I would have liked Universal Login to automatically determine the DB Connection name according to the user's email address. So, instead of the user manually providing some kind of a hint to which DB Connection I should authenticate them against, I would like to automatically determine that somehow.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using hosted login page. The easiest way to determine the **connection** based on client would be to pass the connection parameter when redirecting to **/authorize** endpoint. Thus, Lock will use the connection parameter passed in the URL as the connection to validate the user. For example:

```
 https://[tenant]/authorize?
 client_id=K8B5DJdStcZtUzbhaxAOzCrXNbo2kmXG&
 response_type=token%20id_token&
 redirect_uri=http://application_url&
 scope=openid%20profile%20email%20&
 connection=connection_name&state=123&nonce=345
```

Both auth0.js and auth0-spa-js can be used to pass the extra parameter(connection).

Second approach would be to use [connectionResolver](https://github.com/auth0/lock#other-options) options if you are using Hosted Login Page+ Lock .

**connectionResolver {Function}: When in use, provides an extensibility point to make it possible to choose which connection to use based on the username information. Has username, context, and callback as parameters. The callback expects an object like: {type: 'database', name: 'connection name'}.**

```
var options = {
  connectionResolver: function (username, context, cb) {
    var domain = username.includes('@') && username.split('@')[1];
    if (domain) {
      // If the username is test@auth0.com, the connection used will be the `auth0.com` connection.
      // Make sure you have a database connection with the name `auth0.com`.
      cb({ type: 'database', name: domain });
    } else {
      // Use the default approach to figure it out the connection
      cb(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of username, you can take advantage of [context](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/references/context-object) object to identify the client (`context.clientID`) and choose the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'm really sorry but I guess I wasn't clear in my question: I want to determine the DB Connection to use based upon the email entered by the user. So I'm referring to the user here as "client" not meaning the Auth0 client. I'll try to update the question to reflect this.